# Dimensionality reduction: RBM autoencoders vs. de-noising autoencoders

Tags: dimensionality-reduction, deep-learning, deep-belief-networks, autoencoders

I am looking at non-linear dimensionality reduction techniques and am currently trying to understand the practical differences between different autoencoder approaches:

Can somebody point me to a comparison between RBM initialised autoencoders (Hinton) vs. de-noising autoencoders for dimensionality reduction?

Of course I am interesed in performace characteristics but also in more practical issues, such the reliability of finding a good solution and the computational cost of training.

Answer (score 1):

Whilst not a direct answer to the comparison of RBM and Autoencoder, you might find the MATLAB toolbox for dimensionality reduction [here](https://lvdmaaten.github.io/drtoolbox/) very useful. The code is open source, there is an accompanying white paper, and autoencoders are one of the 34 techniques available.

Answer (score 1):

The original stacked denoising autoencoder paper contains some comparisons to deep belief networks (i.e. stacked RBMs)

> [Vincent et al. (2010)](http://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/download?doi=10.1.1.297.3484&rep=rep1&type=pdf). Stacked denoising autoencoders: Learning useful representations in a deep network with a local denoising criterion.

However, the comparisons are about classification performance, using the models in generative mode (to synthesize examples), and conceptual points (how the methods work). As far as I recall, they don't directly address your questions about computational cost, etc.